# Как обработать события click правильно?

Tags: javascript, jquery

В блоке два одинаковых элемента, нужно обработать события клика так чтобы `dropdown` открывался только у элемента на который кликнули

```js
$(document)
  .on('click', '.b-calc__group-input_right', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.b-calc__dropdown').addClass('b-calc__dropdown_open');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="b-calc__group">
  <div class="b-calc__group-input b-calc__group-input_left">
    <label class="b-calc__label" for="val">You pay</label>
    <input class="b-calc__input" name="val" type="text" placeholder="100">
  </div>
  <div class="b-calc__group-input b-calc__group-input_right">
    <div class="b-calc__currency">
      <i class="cc BTC-alt b-calc__icon"></i> EUR
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="b-calc__dropdown">
    <div class="b-calc__topline">
      <div class="b-calc__search-icon"></div>
      <input class="b-calc__dropdown-input" name="val" type="text" placeholder="Type a currency">
      <a href="#" class="b-calc__closed"></a>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="b-calc__link b-calc__link_eur"><i class="cc BTC-alt b-calc__link-icon"></i>EUR Euro</a>
    <a href="#" class="b-calc__link b-calc__link_usd"><i class="cc BTC-alt b-calc__link-icon"></i>USD Dollar</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="b-calc__group">
  <div class="b-calc__group-input b-calc__group-input_left">
    <label class="b-calc__label" for="val-other">You get</label>
    <input class="b-calc__input" name="val-other" type="text" placeholder="100">
  </div>
  <div class="b-calc__group-input b-calc__group-input_right">
    <div class="b-calc__currency">
      <i class="cc BTC-alt b-calc__icon"></i> BIT
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="b-calc__dropdown">
    <div class="b-calc__topline">
      <div class="b-calc__search-icon"></div>
      <input class="b-calc__dropdown-input" name="val" type="text" placeholder="Type a currency">
      <a href="#" class="b-calc__closed"></a>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="b-calc__link b-calc__link_eur"><i class="cc BTC-alt b-calc__link-icon"></i>EUR Euro</a>
    <a href="#" class="b-calc__link b-calc__link_usd"><i class="cc BTC-alt b-calc__link-icon"></i>USD Dollar</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: посмотри теперь .. немного переделал ответ

Answer (score 0):

если у тебя  первый соответствует левому второй правому 
 то для правого:

```
$(document)
  .on('click', '.b-calc__group-input_right', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.b-calc__dropdown').eq(1).addClass('b-calc__dropdown_open');
  });
```

для левого:

```
$(document)
  .on('click', '.b-calc__group-input_left', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.b-calc__dropdown').eq(0).addClass('b-calc__dropdown_open');
  });
```

Comment: не совсем то, сейчас добавлю html

Comment: как видите b-calc__group-input_right не родитель b-calc__dropdown

Comment: так у тебя один дропдаун. он и будет открываться..

Comment: в коде их два а открыватся должен только у того эелемента на который кликнули

Comment: так или помести их в общего родителя..или раздай им уникальные селекторы. а по другому ты никак не сделаешь